# How to implement update mechanism in my django/django rest framework project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I’m trying to do an app which is able to get data from other websites and get updated itself without handling from the user. For instance: when it is 2pm my script is launched in my app, it gets data,  then my database is updated by using my model and serializers/forms.

Do you have an idea that is it possible to do it on a django project? Thanks for all!

Comment: In the past I've used [django-q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this. It allows you to set up scheduled background tasks.

Comment: I use Django Custom Manaement Commands [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) and Cron.

Example, this is my noon location update, that emails me if things were actually updated: 
`0 12 * * * cd /path/to/my/app/ && /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/my/app/manage.py update_location --cron --all --mail` 

..This is as barebones as you can get, i think. If Windows you'd just use taskmanager and same idea